# pgsql query is causing performance issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

My query on PostgreSQL instance is taking a long time to retrieve the result. This query ran for every 30 mins in our application code.

```
select fgh_dk,
       (select dmb
        from fgh_tonee
        where id=fgh_dk),
       ghk_nm,
       SUM(hjlm_sup) as mgh_klmno
from yunm
where fgh_dk is not null
group by fgh_dk, ghk_nm
order by fgh_dk,ghk_nm;
```

Please suggest us best way to rewrite this query.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, such questions can never be answered without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output. But your query is bound to perform better if you do away with the subquery:

```
select yunm.fgh_dk,
       fgh_tonee.dmb,
       yunm.ghk_nm,
       SUM(yunm.hjlm_sup) as mgh_klmno
from yunm
   left join fgh_tonee
      on fgh_tonee.id = yunm.fgh_dk
where yunm.fgh_dk is not null
group by yunm.fgh_dk, yunm.ghk_nm, fgh_tonee.dmb
order by yunm.fgh_dk, yunm.ghk_nm, fgh_tonee.dmb;
```

Comment: Don't you need to include `fgh_tonee.dmb` in the group clause?  I am surprised this is not necessary with the original query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right.

Comment: I still don't really understand why it's not necessary for the original query: https://dbfiddle.uk/thcnWrVw

Comment: Inline subquery returns only one value and it is dependent from the correlated ID so it need not to be in `group by` @a_horse_with_no_name. A "best" paractice in the joined query is to use `max(fgh_tonee.dmb) dmb` along with explaining comment `/* max = min */`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: thanks, I did not expect the parser to be smart enough to detect that dependency ;)